# shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation Getting called twice on launch

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, screen-orientation, uiinterfaceorientation

I am working on iOS 5 targeted project.  I am having the orientation method as follows.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{    
  NSLog(@" My Orientation");

  return YES;
}
```

However, when my app is launched, my log message will be displayed twice on console, i.e.  My `Orientation` will be displayed twice. I am testing my app in simulator and this is happening just on launch without even changing the `orientation` and then again even on changing the orientation. i.e.,

```
(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

is getting called twice every time, which I suppose is not a correct behavior.Any help is

appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem with this being called twice? BTW, you are supposed to return YES or NO.

Comment: IMO its normal behaviour, supportedOrientations in iOS6 is called even about 10 times on start and also twice on every rotation.

Comment: Yes, I observed the same. And I did not jet identify any reasonalbe pattern. To me it just did not matter much. That's why I asked what the actual problem is.

Comment: Why do you suppose it's incorrect behaviour? Where in the documentation does it say that it only gets called once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing you have done. Apple has made the device react to this many times. It just depends on what the app is doing. Perhaps a view load, or something else causes it to fire again. However, is this really a problem? In most cases, it is not (Or at least shouldn't be).

If it really is a problem, then perhaps someone should elaborate. However, at least from my experience, this is common behavior. I am not aware of any way to solve this.

I suppose if this really bothers you and there is no way to fix, you could file a bug to Apple.

Answer (score 0):

I also made the experience that shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation is calles always twice.
Interesting detail: My experience was, that self.view.frame in the first call holds the "old" values ( from where it cames ) and in the second call the "new" values (where it goes)